# LM324A Output Current in TI datasheet

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm a little confused about the *Output Current* block(s) in the TI LM2902/324A [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2902-n.pdf). Specifically regarding Section 6.5 (pages 5-6).

In this section, there are two *Output Current* blocks and, whereas the specs between the two blocks are quite different, I don't see how the parameters differ - except where one explicitly states that T=25C.

Could someone explain this?

*Note: please ignore the Vo=200mV condition from the first block; I should have excluded that from my highlight below.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is specified at \$T_A=25^\circ\:\textrm{C}\$. The other is specified at \$0^\circ\:\textrm{C}\le T_A\le 70^\circ\:\textrm{C}\$. But I also now believe that the upper row of the ***sink*** specification for \$T_A=25^\circ\:\textrm{C}\$ and for \$V_O=2\:\textrm{V}\$ should be interpreted as a mistake on their part. That's in \$\textrm{mA}\$ and not in \$\mu\textrm{A}\$.

The person drawing lines for the tables messed up, is all.

Take a look at the OnSemi one and I think you will see that I'm right: [LM324](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM324-D.PDF)

[image]

Comment: Thanks jonk: I mentioned that thermal parameter in my question. The problem is that the specs don't overlap. For instance, the sink current at T=25C shows typical 20 uA, whereas for 0<= T <= 70C, typical is 8 mA (for 324).

Comment: @BlairFonville Okay. I've updated my reply.

Comment: Thanks for the research, jonk. A typo certainly makes sense. PS sorry for the delay in accepting this; I was out for the day.

Comment: @BlairFonville Good catch on your part! I did +1 you for it. And don't worry on my account about accepting. Doing it should be mostly about keeping others from wasting added time when its not needed.